# Refactoring class member initialization C++

Tags: c++

Have this code do what I want: If there is argument pass to constructor, initialize; otherwise, set it to default value?

```
class Node
  {
  public:
    Node(string id, bool isNum, int level, string data, bool duplicate, Node *next)
      : id(id), isNum(isNum), level(level), data(data), duplicate(duplicate), next(next) {}

  private:
    string id;
    bool isNum = false;
    int level = 0;
    string data;
    bool duplicate = false;
    Node *next = nullptr;
  };
```

Comment: It's usually a good idea to write the initialisers in the same order as the members, to avoid reader confusion when there's a dependency - remember that initialisers execute in the order the members appear, not the order the initialisers are written!

Answer (score 1):

`Node(string id ={}, bool isNum=false, int level=0, string data={}, bool duplicate=false, Node* next={})`

Put the defaults in the argument list.  That way you can leave off any number of trailing arguments.

With Pepijn Kramer's answer, you only have two choices: give all the parameters or give exactly 2 parameters.  You would need to overload 6 different forms, each taking a different number of arguments, to get the same feature that way.

You might want to give distinct overloaded functions for *some* of them, though.  Specifically, a constructor called with 0 arguments is a default constructor, and a constructor called with exactly 1 argument might be an implicit conversion and you can mark it `explicit` to prevent that.

If the constructors are being inlined anyway, then the default arguments is no less efficient than having distinct constructors.  But you might want to mark the one-argument case as `explicit` and *not* mark the others, so it needs to be on its own.

Comment: "A constructor that can be called with one argument" isn't identical to "a constructor with exactly 1 argument".  The first line of your answer shows a 6-argument constructor that is also a converting constructor (and also a default constructor).

Comment: @TobySpeight I clarified the wording.  I was referring to the call, not the total number of arguments declared.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use default arguments, but provide various overloaded constructors like this

```
#include <string>

class Node
{
public:
    // pass string by const reference, this avoids unecessary copying of the string
    // pass all other arguments as const, initializer is not supposed to change them
    Node(const std::string& id, const std::string data, const bool isNum, const int level, const bool duplicate, Node* next) :
        m_id(id),
        m_data(data),
        m_isNum(isNum),
        m_level(level),
        m_duplicate(duplicate),
        m_next(next)
    {
    }

    Node(const std::string& id, const std::string& data) :
        m_id(id),
        m_data(data)
        // rest of the members will be default initialized
    {
    }

private:
    // changed the order so that all non-default initialized members
    // are listed together.
    std::string m_id;
    std::string m_data;
    bool m_isNum = false;
    int m_level = 0;
    bool m_duplicate = false;
    Node* m_next = nullptr;
};
```

Comment: `Node(const std::string& id, const std::string data, const bool isNum, const int level, const bool duplicate, Node* next) :
        m_id(id),
        m_data(data),
        m_isNum(isNum),
        m_level(level),
        m_duplicate(duplicate),
        m_next(next)
    {
    }`

If I use like this: `new Node(1, "data", true)`, will the rest of data member be default initialized? If yes, why you declare overload constructor?

Comment: It's generally better to pass the strings by value, then move-initialise the members from them.  That saves a copy when passing rvalues (e.g. when a string literal is implicitly converted to `std::string`).  Always assuming that `string` in the code is an alias to `std::string`, but there's no evidence of that in the fragment we're given, of course!